# A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter while Array Resize

Tags: c#

While I try to resize an array in C# as below,

```
Array.Resize(ref Globals.NameList, 0);
```

I get the below error

```
A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter
```

Globals is an object. NameList is a string type array declared in Globals Class.

Please help me to fix this by posting the correct code.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a more information.
Same error occur when we use a property as out parameter in int.TryParse(). In this case also we need a intermediate variable to do the operation. Then assign the variable's value to the property.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

use variable, but not property

```
var obj = Globals.NameList;
Array.Resize(ref obj , 0);
Globals.NameList=obj;
```

Comment: Correct, but since the new size is `0` it's a little overkill.

Comment: Thank you burning_LEGION.. That fixed it :)

Answer (score 10):

The compiler error speaks for itself - you can't pass a property by reference; only a variable.

From the C# spec section 10.6.1.2:

> When a formal parameter is a reference parameter, the corresponding argument in a method invocation must consist of the keyword `ref` followed by a *variable-reference* (section 5.3.3) of the same type as the formal parameter.

A property access expression doesn't count as a *variable-reference*.

You probably want:

```
var tmp = Globals.NameList;
Array.Reize(ref tmp, 0);
Globals.NameList = tmp;
```

Note that VB *does* allow passing a property by reference, but it acts like the above. In particular, each assignment within the method will only affect a *temporary* value, rather than being a call to the relevant setter.

Also note that having a class called `Globals` with mutable public properties is a design smell...

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet. In case this is not a good approach, if I need to group few global variables and objects that should be made accessible to whole application what should be the best practice ?

Comment: Jon Skeet.. I cannot accept multiple post as answer ? Wanted to accept your comment also as an answer. Currently I cannot upvote your post at my level :)

Comment: @codebug: You can only accept one post, yes. Accept whichever is most helpful to you. As for the design - try to avoid *needing* "objects that should be made accessible to the whole application". Look into using dependency injection to allow each class to express what it needs.

Answer (score 0):

do

```
Array arr = Globals.NameList;
Array.Resize(ref arr, 0);
Globals.NameList = arr;
```